# How to resize captured image before store in sdcard?

Tags: android

I am developing a application in which I want to resize captured image before store it in specified folder of sdcard.

I have used all the permissions required for write the data in sdcard but still I am unable to do it.

my code:

```
try{
    Bitmap bitmap = Constant.decodeFile(fileName);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 480, 320, true);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);

    File f = new File(fileName.toString());
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (OutOfMemoryError o) {
        o.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Can I ask.. how do you verify that the image is not resized? Do you look at the file size or the image `width x height`? What is the output you get and what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgot to flush the Stream after writing data into into. use `FileOutputStream.flush()` after writing data... and 
try this...

```
File file = new File(fileName.toString());
try {
    FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    stream.flush();
    stream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

Comment: What is flush() exactly for ?

Comment: @Stebra see here http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush%28%29

Comment: @Stebra flush() ensures that all the data in Stream written out to the underlying file.

Comment: Yeah, figured it out thanks. And tw, I was also wondering why is it downwoted. I think it's a good answer...I'll upvote that for you once I can vote again, in several hours ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice tutorial on resizing images:

```
BitmapScaler scaler = new BitmapScaler(getResources(), R.drawable.moorwen, newWidth);
imageView.setImageBitmap(scaler.getScaled());
```

BitmapScaler class follows:

```
class BitmapScaler {
    private static class Size {
        int sample;
        float scale;
    }

    private Bitmap scaled;

    BitmapScaler(Resources resources, int resId, int newWidth)
            throws IOException {
        Size size = getRoughSize(resources, resId, newWidth);
        roughScaleImage(resources, resId, size);
        scaleImage(newWidth);
    }

    BitmapScaler(File file, int newWidth) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(file);
            Size size = getRoughSize(is, newWidth);
            try {
                is = new FileInputStream(file);
                roughScaleImage(is, size);
                scaleImage(newWidth);
            } finally {
                is.close();
            }
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
    }

    BitmapScaler(AssetManager manager, String assetName, int newWidth)
            throws IOException {
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = manager.open(assetName);
            Size size = getRoughSize(is, newWidth);
            try {
                is = manager.open(assetName);
                roughScaleImage(is, size);
                scaleImage(newWidth);
            } finally {
                is.close();
            }
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
    }

    Bitmap getScaled() {
        return scaled;
    }

    private void scaleImage(int newWidth) {
        int width = scaled.getWidth();
        int height = scaled.getHeight();

        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float ratio = ((float) scaled.getWidth()) / newWidth;
        int newHeight = (int) (height / ratio);
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

        scaled = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaled, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
    }

    private void roughScaleImage(InputStream is, Size size) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(size.scale, size.scale);

        BitmapFactory.Options scaledOpts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        scaledOpts.inSampleSize = size.sample;
        scaled = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, scaledOpts);
    }

    private void roughScaleImage(Resources resources, int resId, Size size) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(size.scale, size.scale);

        BitmapFactory.Options scaledOpts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        scaledOpts.inSampleSize = size.sample;
        scaled = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, resId, scaledOpts);
    }

    private Size getRoughSize(InputStream is, int newWidth) {
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, o);

        Size size = getRoughSize(o.outWidth, o.outHeight, newWidth);
        return size;
    }

    private Size getRoughSize(Resources resources, int resId, int newWidth) {
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, resId, o);

        Size size = getRoughSize(o.outWidth, o.outHeight, newWidth);
        return size;
    }

    private Size getRoughSize(int outWidth, int outHeight, int newWidth) {
        Size size = new Size();
        size.scale = outWidth / newWidth;
        size.sample = 1;

        int width = outWidth;
        int height = outHeight;

        int newHeight = (int) (outHeight / size.scale);

        while (true) {
            if (width / 2 < newWidth || height / 2 < newHeight) {
                break;
            }
            width /= 2;
            height /= 2;
            size.sample *= 2;
        }
        return size;
    }
}
```

http://zerocredibility.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/android-bitmap-scaling/

Answer (score 1):

You can use **createBitmap()** to resize the original image.

FOllowing are the parameters:

(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height)

**source**  The bitmap we are subsetting

**x**   The x coordinate of the first pixel in source

**y**   The y coordinate of the first pixel in source

**width**   The number of pixels in each row

**height**  The number of rows

Example:

```
Bitmap newbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap, 2, 2, bitmap.getWidth() - 4, bitmap.getHeight() - 120);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using PNG format then it will not compress your image because PNG is a lossless format. use JPEG for compressing your your image and use 0 instead of 100 in quality.

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem exactly? Doesn't your code manage to open the file ? does it crash or have you just no error, but no output file?

By the way, you should call bitmap.recycle() at the end

Answer (score 0):

It could help you harry
[crop-image](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/12/15/crop-image-android/)

Answer (score 0):

```
BitmapFactory.Options optionsSignature = new BitmapFactory.Options();
final Bitmap bitmapSignature = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(
fileUriSignature.getPath(), optionsSignature);
Bitmap resizedSignature = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapSignature, 256, 128, true);
signature.setImageBitmap(resizedSignature);
```

Comment: Please explain your Ans.

Comment: Intially I'm getting image to bitmapSignature, after that using Bitmap.createScaledBitmap() method I'm re-sizing captured image which stored in  bitmapSignature into 256* 128 size image...